# Linq XML query the descendants of parent with a specific value in attribute

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I need some help with some LINQ to XML.  I've the below XML;

```
<GcctTestData>
  <TestDriveRequest Record="1">
    <element name="Time Zone">(GMT+05:30)</element>
    <element name="Requested Dealer">Concorde</element>
    <element name="Model Year">1999</element>
    <element name="Make">Tata</element>
    <element name="Model/Vehicle Line">Indica</element>
  </TestDriveRequest>
  <TestDriveRequest Record="2">
    <element name="Time Zone">(GMT+05:30)</element>
    <element name="Requested Dealer">Kun"</element>
    <element name="Model Year">2020"</element>
    <element name="Make">BMW"</element>
    <element name="Model/Vehicle Line">3-series</element>
  </TestDriveRequest>
  <TestDriveRequest Record="3">
    <element name="Time Zone">(GMT+05:30)</element>
    <element name="Requested Dealer">KUN Hyundai</element>
    <element name="Model Year">2001</element>
    <element name="Make">Hyundai</element>
    <element name="Model/Vehicle Line">Verna</element>
  </TestDriveRequest>
</GcctTestData>
```

I tried it like below:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements =
                from element in root.Elements("TestDriveRequest")
                where element.Attribute("Record").Value == "1"
                select element;

            foreach (XElement el in xElements.Descendants().Where(p => !p.HasElements))
            {
                int keyInt = 0;
                string keyName = el.Attribute("name").Value;

                while (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(keyName))
                {
                    keyName = $"{el.Attribute("name").Value}_{keyInt++}";
                }
                keyValuePairs.Add(keyName, el.Value);
            }
```

I'll have to get the element **name** attribute value of the **element** for that parent which have the record value **1**

but the linq query is not fetching it...

After implementing the suggestion of @anu-viswan I face the below problem
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `root.Descendants` instead of `root.Elements`.

For example,

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements =   from element in root.Descendants("TestDriveRequest")
                where element.Attribute("Record").Value == "1"
                select element;
```

**XContainer.Elements**

> Returns a filtered collection of the child elements of this element or
>   document, in document order. Only elements that have a matching XName
>   are included in the collection.

**XContainer.Descendants**

> Returns a filtered collection of the descendant elements for this
>   document or element, in document order. Only elements that have a
>   matching XName are included in the collection  Output

**Complete Code**

```
IEnumerable<XElement> xElements =   from element in root.Descendants("TestDriveRequest")
            where element.Attribute("Record").Value == "1"
            select element;

foreach (XElement el in xElements.Descendants().Where(p => !p.HasElements))
{
   int keyInt = 0;
   string keyName = el.Attribute("name").Value;

   while (keyValuePairs.ContainsKey(keyName))
   {
     keyName = $"{el.Attribute("name").Value}_{keyInt++}";
   }
   keyValuePairs.Add(keyName, el.Value);
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

Comment: Now I'm facing the error **System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**
At this line **foreach (XElement el in xElements.Descendants().Where(p => !p.HasElements))**

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would create the dictionary :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace AscendingSequences
{
    class AscendingSequences
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, string>> dict = doc.Descendants("TestDriveRequest")
                .GroupBy(x => (int)x.Attribute("Record"), y => y.Elements("element")
                    .GroupBy(a => (string)a.Attribute("name"), b => (string)b)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.FirstOrDefault()))
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());
        }
    }
}
```